# change content based on url per plugin

Tags: plugins, urls

I have a wordpress page that uses a custom template I created. The url looks like this:

```
http://localhost/custom
```

What I want to do, is have the content for this page change, depending on the *action* (is that what you call it?). e.g.

```
http://localhost/custom/people
http://localhost/custom/animals
http://localhost/custom/places
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: How have you set those up? Is that a "Page" named "custom" and several child pages?

Comment: @s_ha_dum "custom" is a page I setup, but all the sub-pages will be dynamically created based on wordpress taxonomy categories

Comment: Have you tried an [endpoint](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91195/73)?