# Post's ID pattern?

Tags: php, urls, include

Each post has an ID and I would like to know how they were assigned. Is there a pattern? Why are the ID's not being incremented by 1 every posts? It would be easier..My ID's go from 9867, to 9869, to 9864, etc.. I can't seem to find a pattern.

I could use "The Loop", but I'm doing that from another site. I want to include the last 30 posts of my wordpress site, so I need to find a pattern in the url to get the last 30 posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each auto-draft gets its own ID, each revision, each nav item, page, custom post type …

The actual ID of a post should be irrelevant, this is really just needed for the database and ugly permalinks.

You cannot get the last 30 items by inspecting the post ID only.

Install a [REST API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/86960/using-the-rewrite-api-to-construct-a-restful-url/91195#91195) on the other site and a rule to get the last x items.

Comment: Then how can I retrieve the last 30 items from an external domain?

Comment: @Maxwell See my update.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like a very complicated solution though.

Comment: If you take my code it is done in less than 20 minutes. Really not that complicated. :)

Comment: 20 mins for _you_, @toscho :)

Comment: @vancoder Actually, I think _I_ would need less than 3 minutes. It is my code after all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the RSS feed - typically at `http:/sitename/feed`.

You can set the number of items the fed contains by changing the value *Syndication feeds show the most recent* in `Settings > Reading`

Comment: This is a very vague 'answer'.

Comment: @vancoder Feel free to improve it or leave your own answer :)

Comment: I only leave answers when I have one to leave :)