# How to obfuscate theme directory URLs

Tags: theme-development, images, url-rewriting

I'm rewriting this question because I realized it was totally unclear what I want to do. I'm looking for a way to "obscure" the theme directory so that absolute URLs that reference things like images and stylesheets in that theme directory don't have the "wp-content/themes/my_theme/" structure, but are rather more direct, like a normal website, eg: "/images/my_image.gif" and "/css/stylesheet.css".

It's easy to hard-code the path to your theme's folder using the recommended [get_template_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) to programmatically bring up the theme folder, but the theme folder structure is completely exposed this way.

I'm hoping that the answer can leverage `wp_rewrite` in some way, because the only other solution I can think of involves editing `.htaccess` and that means hard-coding the theme directory into your htaccess file. I suppose this could be automated via a plugin or your theme activation function that edits the htaccess file, but I'm hoping that someone out there knows of a more "built-in" way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `get_template_directory_uri()`:

```
$url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/myimage.jpg';
```

This function will always return the correct path to your theme.

If you want to hide/shorten that URL, you could [use an endpoint](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91195/73), maybe `img`. The downside is, you load the complete WordPress for each image request.

Or use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^img/([a-z\d-])\.png /wp-content/themes/my_theme/img/$1.png [L]
```

This will not work in a standalone theme.

Comment: I'm sorry Toscho, I should have been more clear in my OP. Obviously I know about get_template_directory_uri() etc. But that will spit out http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/ which is not what I want. Maybe I need to rewrite my OP to be more clear.

Comment: @TomAuger I was already wondering what happened to you. :D I made an update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Toscho. I realize that my original question was a bit silly, considering that WordPress exposes the theme directory and URI in so many other ways. I really appreciate your link to your other post on Endpoints. Lots to learn there!