# Show page without reference to post (like front-page)

Tags: redirect, slug

I created a plugin that adds a new post-type `awards`. Each award has multiple votes attached, which are stored in a custom table, created by the plugin.

Now I need to show two different overview-pages for the award:

1. "mysite.com/awards" - show a list of all awards (simple)
2. "mysite.com/votes" - show a list of all votes (problem)

The first part is simple: I create a theme file with the name "archive-award.php" and display the list.

**I need help with the second case**: A `vote` is not a custom post-type, so I cannot simply create an `archive-votes.php` file. This page has absolutely no relation to any item in the posts-table.

My idea is that I create a theme file (e.g. `list-votes.php`) and then link it with a custom slug. So the slug `votes` would open the theme file `list-votes.php` - but I could not find out how to do this.

Only solution which is not very good in my eyes is to create a page called `votes` and then add a short-code on that page which will display the list.

Comment: Are you looking for an [endpoint](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91195/73)?

Comment: Good point. I think I can solve this using an endpoint...

Comment: (ab)using page is actually quite common approach (and can be rather clean with dedicated template for it). Otherwise endpoint for more involved approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to toschos hint I could solve the problem. This is the code that I use:

```
// Register the endpoint
function my_init() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint('votes', EP_ALL);
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');


// Execute a function when the endpoint is called
function my_redirect() {
    global $wp_query;

    if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['votes'])) {
        $wp_query->is_404 = false;
        add_filter( 'wp_title', 'my_title_votes', 10, 2 );
        // this will output the template-file "all-votes.php"
        get_template_part( 'all-votes' );
        // Prevent WordPress from adding the front-page or 404 page to my output...
        die();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_redirect' );

function my_title_votes( $title, $sep ) {
    return 'Votes-Title ' . $sep . ' ' .  $title;
}
```

When I open the URL mysite.com/votes/ I get my custom output, even though there is no page with that slug :-)