# Link Forms on Wordpress

Tags: plugins, forms

On our Wordpress site, we have a form that consists of a series of (radio button style) questions.  Depending on which answer the user provides to a particular question, we'd like to show the user a different form.  That is, we would like to link multiple forms to our one main form.  Is this possible? If so, can someone explain how to do this, or point me to any kind of resource that might help? I am very new to Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hierarchical custom post type and create a post for each form. Child forms are then set under a parent, their slug or a post meta field connected to the answers of their parent form.

When the form is submitted, you use the answer to select the best matching child and the you show that child form.

---

Another approach.

1. Create a [special endpoint](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91195/73), let’s say `submit` with the sub-type `step`.

On the main page, show the form. When the submission is a `POST` request, validate the submitted data and either show the same for again to correct user errors or …

2. Create a new post for that company with `wp_insert_post()`. This function returns a post ID. Redirect the user to the next step (`/submit/step/2`) and show the next form. Add the post ID as hidden field, and set a cookie for the user, so you can track the progress.
3. Again, when that form is processed lead to step 3 or a success message.

Comment: Can you link me to where they describe heirarchical custom post types - haven't heard of these before.

Comment: Sorry - apparently hitting enter submits the comment.  But I would also like to know if that would match the criteria for the following example: I have a form that creates a new company and a post generated from that form. Then I have a multiple forms for products based on the type of company. I still want to generate a product post based on the form for every submission. Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh, now I get what you are out for. I think another approach than my first suggestion would be better.