# How to trigger an action with a URL

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am writing a plugin that needs to trigger an action based on URL's. The url scheme is the following:

```
mywordpresssite.com/action/12345
```

where `12345` is a unique code used by the function triggered. My question is how can I trigger a function in the plugin based on such a link?

**EDIT**
Thanks to the answers below I wrote the 3 following functions but I don't have what I want yet. add_

```
function add_endpoint(){
     error_log('add_endpoint');
     add_rewrite_endpoint( 'action', EP_ROOT );
}
add_action('init',  'add_endpoint', 0);

function add_query_vars($vars){
     error_log("query");
     $vars[] = 'action';
     return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', add_query_vars, 0);


function sniff_requests(){
    global $wp;
    error_log("request sniffed:".$wp->query_vars['action']);
}
add_filter('parse_request', sniff_requests, 0);
```

And the log says that all functions are triggered but it fails to display `$wp->query_vars['action']`. My guess is that the rewrite rule is not recognized by the system:

```
[26-Aug-2013 22:22:35 UTC] add_endpoint
[26-Aug-2013 22:22:35 UTC] query
[26-Aug-2013 22:22:35 UTC] request sniffed:
```

Comment: I think, you need an [endpoint](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/86960/73).

Comment: I edited my question with the code to create the endpoint. However WP doesn't seem to handle it. Could you have a look and tell me what I am missing? Thanks

Comment: did you flush rewrite rules?

Comment: At activation and de-activation. But shouldn't they get flushed after the endpoint is added (init)?

Comment: they should not be flushed on init, that will flush them on every request, but you have to be sure to add the endpoint first on activation if that's where you're flushing them. a simple way to flush for testing is to visit the permalinks settings page in admin. aside from your unquoted function names in your add_filter calls, which I assume are typos, your code works for me. adding `action` to query vars is redundant though, that can be removed. add_rewrite_endpoint already adds it to query vars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @toscho says you need an endpoint.

Note code is **untested**.

```
/**
* Flush rewrite rules
*/
function install_my_plugin() {
    my_plugin_endpoint();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'install_my_plugin' );

/**
* Flush rewrite rules
*/
function unistall_my_plugin() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'unistall_my_plugin' );

/**
* Add the endpoint
*/
function my_plugin_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'action', EP_ROOT );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_plugin_endpoint' );


function my_plugin_proxy_function( $query ) {    
  if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
    // this is for security!
    $allowed_actions = array('123', '124', '125');
    $action = $query->get('action');
    if ( in_array($action, $allowed_actions) ) {
      switch ( $action ) {
        case '123' :
          return call_user_func('function_123');
        case '124' :
          return call_user_func('function_124');
        case '125' :
          return call_user_func('function_125');
      }
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_plugin_proxy_function' );
```

Comment: probably don't want to hook `pre_get_posts`, it'll get triggered for every query on the page.

Comment: I edited my question with what I did based on your answer but the enpoint seems not recognized by wp. Could you please have a look?

Comment: @NathanZ in my code there was a big error, WP_Query has **not** a method called `get_query_var`, the right method is `get`. Shame on me. For now I've corrected it, let me do some tests and I'll give feedback.

Comment: @Milo, do you think that a `in_array` check for every page can slow down the page loading? If so, what hook do you suggest? I usually use `pre_get_posts` in similar cases, because is the first available where condional tags work, but if there is one better I'm ready to change :)

Comment: @G.M. I missed the part where you're checking the query object passed to the `pre_get_posts` function, so that shouldn't trigger on multiple queries. you could maybe wrap that in `if( $query->is_main_query() )` to only execute it for the main query.

Comment: Good catch @Milo I swear I usually do it... :)

Comment: @NathanZ after correct my code, I've also added the Milo suggestion to check if in the main query. I've done some tests, and it seems to work now.

Comment: Thank you both very much. It works. Can you just explain a last thing. If I add the endpoint at activation, why add it again at 'init'?

Comment: @NathanZ on init it ensures that the query var used by the endpoint is added to the wp query vars. On activaction is needed because before flashing rules I need the endpopint is added.